# How can I prevent Chrome from downloading a picture again?

Tags: google-chrome

Today I've wanted to download this quite big picture ([link](http://ehdwallpapers.com/wallpapers/amazing-nature-corner-1366x768.jpg)) after I had seen it. I noticed that it took quite a lot of time although I obviously downloaded it before (as it was on my screen).

How can I just save to image file I see without having to download it again?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the image should be cached (unless you viewed it in an Incognito session). I can't tell you by what rules files are deleted from the cache and when.

If this happens a lot, maybe you could try [increase the cache size](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=098d42a41aacdc6d&hl=en).

Comment: So it happens randomly? Why doesn't Chrome have a picture I am currently watching in the cache? As I can see it, it has to be stored somewhere! (btw. according to "chrome://net-internals/#httpCache" my cache size is about 315MB. That should be enought, shouldn't it?). A good post how to increase the cache size is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/104415/how-do-i-increase-cache-size-in-chrome

Comment: While it may feel random, I don't think it is. For example, I would assume a large picture that you only viewed once will be removed from the cache sooner than the logo image of a website you visit all the time (like the superuser logo on this site).

Comment: It might be true that the picture is not in the cache - but it has to be stored somewhere (on my computer). If it wasn't stored on my computer I would have to download it again each time I switch tabs. This is definitely not the case. So if it is stored somewhere on my notebook, I would like to copy it from this location and don't download it again.

Comment: While your tab with the image is still open, the file is most likely in the cache. It could also be loaded directly into memory without any actual file existing on the hard drive.